# AWS filtering and exporting logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I have a use case - I have to stream and store logs on s3 but not all logs from cloudtrail, just particular filtered groups. I found nice solution but it has limitation. Natively i can do it by - applying subscription filter on a log group and this filter shoots logs to kinesis firehose. Which is good but one log group can only has one subscription filter and one trail - one log group.
Do I have to create one trail per one filter ? Seems like an overkill. I am searching for possible solutions to archive this. Tbh i want to avoid using lambda and athena but if this is the only solution I will go for it. Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Don't ask my why it has to be like that ... :D security compliance

Comment: Instead of streaming to Firehose, you can stream to Lambda. The lambda will do the filtering and distribute the log entries to their respective buckets.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, that is a good suggestion

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind, I can put it as an answer with some extra info.

Comment: Are you _just_ processing CloudTrail logs? And is there a reason that you can't send those logs to S3 rather than CloudWatch?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments.

A **suggested solution** to the issue is to setup a [subscription filter to lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample), instead of to Firehose stream.

The lambda function could process the log entries and based on its own filtering rules, **direct different log rectords** respective to their respective destinations. This could involve directly writing to given S3 buckets, or to different Firehose streams.